# Read path variable in Think PHP

Tags: path-variables, thinkphp

I am using the format `$pathVariable = $request->param('variableName/s', '');` to read path variable from ThinkPHP but am not successful. What is the right way to read path variable from URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$param = $this->request->param();
```

like this